IR vol trading and market making, how it works
I feel like I am familiar with index vol trading but less with IR vol trading.
What types of instruments are actually traded on IR vol desks at banks? Is it only swaptions or other products are also traded? I feel like swaptions are the most liquid in that space so it's the most traded instrument? So do you have a lot of flow coming or most of your time you are pricing instruments?
How are these instruments actually traded on a desk? Do you just take the spread when doing market making and expect that you have a good pricing model like SABR? Or you actually have a vision on rates vol?
I've also seen banks where people trades rates vol in Gamma pod or Vega pod and was wondering what was the difference? Like for Gamma pod you hedge Vega and Delta?
Thanks

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
